# Python Pandas Conditional Formatting of Dataframe without Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting of a dataframe and save it has html. If I dont use a Jupyter notebook the program crashes.

How can I write an html without using Jupyter?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

def highlight_vals(val, min=-0.5, max=0.5, color='green'):
    if min < val < max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''
with open('filename.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['B', 'C', 'D'])
                    .set_table_attributes("border=1").render())
```

**Error**

Program crashes: The Python REPL process has exited

Comment: For me it working nice, under win7, python 3.6 and pandas 0.24.1

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.6 64bit. I am using Pandas 0.23. How are you running the script?